# `mapStateToProps` is not triggered after reducers in react-redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I am playing with react, redux, react-redux and redux-sagas. I have a Components that once mounted perform an API call, and when the call is performed, data should be added within the component.

If I understand correctly,

- `mapDispatchToProps` is used to inject `dispatch` function within the component
- `mapStateToProps` is used to update the component if react's store is changed
- `sagas` are used to trigger async function when message is sent to redux
- `reducers` are used to change react's store when message is sent to redux

However, in my project, when the component is mounted, API call is triggered,  store is changed, but `mapStateToProps` is not called, so my component does not display the result.

I have no idea how to debug this.

Did I miss something ?

`sagas/index.js`

```
function* loadLinks(action) {
    try {
        const links = yield call(linksSearch, action.value);
        yield put({type: "LINKS_LOAD_SUCCEEDED", links: links, page: action.value.page});
    } catch (e) {
        yield put({type: "LINKS_LOAD_FAILED", message: {}});
    }
}

function* mySaga() {
    yield [
        takeEvery("LINKS_LOAD_REQUESTED", loadLinks)
    ]
}

export default mySaga;
```

`reducers/index.js`

```
const addLinks = (links, page, state) => {
    const newLinks = [page].reduce((init, page) => {
        init[page]=links;
        return init;
    }, state);
    return Object.assign(newLinks)
};

const requestedLinks = (state = {}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'LINKS_LOAD_SUCCEEDED':
            const newState = addLinks(action.links, action.page, state);
            return newState;
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

const reducer = combineReducers({
    requestedLinks,
});

export default reducer
```

`containers/ConnectedLinksGrid.js`

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
    return {
        links:
            (ownProps.page in state.requestedLinks) ?
                state.requestedLinks[ownProps.page] :
                []
    }

};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
    return {
        loadLinks: () => {
            const value = ownProps;
            dispatch({type: "LINKS_LOAD_REQUESTED", value})
        }
    }
};

const ConnectedLinksGrid = connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(LinksGrid);

export default ConnectedLinksGrid;
```

Note: `<LinksGrid />` calls loadLinks() once mounted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like your `addLinks` function in your reducers file is modifying the state directly with the line `init[page]=links;`, which means when your reducer then returns the new state and redux compares the new state to the old state, there's no difference, which means your component doesn't update.

Also, you shouldn't need the complexity of the addLinks function. You could update your main reducer function like this:

```
const requestedLinks = (state = {}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'LINKS_LOAD_SUCCEEDED':
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
              [action.page]: action.links,
            });
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

Comment: Wow... Thank you very much ! <3